# How to edit nsfetchresults records when only some records are displayed?

Tags: ios, edit, nsfetchrequest, uitableview

I am trying to edit nsfetchresults records from another viewcontroller and it is working fine if all my database entries are displayed. But when I filter the table by date and try to edit it, I get this error

> 2013-03-22 23:09:02.895 easyDB[1079:907] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070 2013-03-22
>   23:09:18.865 easyDB[1079:907] caught exception!
>
> NSInternalInconsistencyException
>
> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

I send it by

```
    NSIndexPath *indexpath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;
            GlucoseDetailViewController *glucoseDetailsVC = (GlucoseDetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
            GlucoseRecords *rec = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexpath];
[glucoseDetailsVC setSentRecord:rec];
```

And in edit view

```
    [self.sentRecord setGlucose:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[txtGlucoseReading text] intValue]]];

    [self.sentRecord setDate:self.dateToAdd];
    [self.sentRecord setMealType:[NSString stringWithString:self.strMealOption]];
    [self.sentRecord setQuickNote:[NSString stringWithString:self.strQuickNote]];
    [self.sentRecord setDeleted:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    [self.sentRecord setWhoRecorded:[self.settings currentUser]];

    NSError *error;
    if (![[self.settings managedObjectContext] save:&error])
        NSLog(@"Failed to add default user with error: %@", [error domain]);
```

FetchedResults Controller

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil && [self.strCurrentEntetyName isEqualToString:self.strEntetyName] &&(self.filteChanged==[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO])) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }


    self.filteChanged = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    self.strCurrentEntetyName = [NSString stringWithString:self.strEntetyName];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[self strEntetyName]];
    //NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
    //                               entityForName:@"Records" inManagedObjectContext:[self.settings managedObjectContext]];

    if (self.isDateFilterSet==[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO])
    {

    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" whoRecorded.username = %@ AND deleted=0", [self.settings.currentUser username]];
    }
    else
    {
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" (whoRecorded.username = %@) AND (deleted = 0) AND (date =>%@) AND (date<=%@)", [self.settings.currentUser username],self.dateMinSetFilter ,self.dateMaxSetFilter];


    }

    NSLog(@"User:%@",[self.settings.currentUser username]);

   // [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:100];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:[self.settings managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;




    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;




    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

I understand what the problem is, but I am not able to see any good way to solve it. I can reset the table to display all the entries before editing but I don't think that's a good solution. Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code for fetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

```
[self.tableView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

Needed to add this line to

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you 'display only some records'? Using NSPredicate to filter the result or anything else?

I think you need to locate the issue, is it because you operate one tableview from another view controller?

Comment: yes, I filter it by date. Sorry for not being clear. I have added that code to question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

before calling parsing method please write: `self.fetchedResultsController = nil;`

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController // attaches an NSFetchRequest to this UITableViewController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil )
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSLog(@"Length:: %d",[[_fetchedResultsController mutableCopy] length]);

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"YourEntityName"];
    [fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:YES];

    // Sort by Application name
    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    //Sort by CommandNameloca
    NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortDescriptor1, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:100];

    tempArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:sortDescriptors];

    NSLog(@"****----- tempArr Count == %d",[tempArr count]);

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"date" cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Please look in the log for array count. It will display the total record you get.
Please share your result. Best Luck.. !!

Comment: -[NSFetchedResultsController mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I get this error. From I modified your code. And looks like that I get the correct amount of entries in my table.